# zlib1g-dev is already installed but shows ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

Tags: python-3.x, pip, zlib, python-3.8, debian-buster

In my Debian 10 OS, I have several Python versions as 2.7, 3.7 and 3.8. For Python 3.8, pip did not work(no module name pip) and I tried to install pip for Python 3.8 with 'sudo python3.8 get-pip.py' and it showed below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 520, in _get_decompress_func
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'zlib'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 568, in _get_data
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 523, in _get_decompress_func
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "get-pip.py", line 23704, in <module>
    main()
  File "get-pip.py", line 198, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "get-pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pip_entry_point
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 241, in load_module
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 709, in _get_module_code
  File "<frozen zipimport>", line 570, in _get_data
zipimport.ZipImportError: can't decompress data; zlib not available
```

Then, I tried to install zlib with 'sudo apt install zlib1g-dev' but it showed that package is already in the system.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
zlib1g-dev is already the newest version (1:1.2.11.dfsg-1).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  adb android-libadb android-libbase android-libboringssl
  android-libcrypto-utils android-libcutils android-liblog
  android-sdk-platform-tools-common arch-test bridge-utils cloud-image-utils
  debootstrap distro-info genisoimage libayatana-appindicator3-1
  libayatana-ido3-0.4-0 libayatana-indicator3-7 libboost-log1.67.0
  libboost-program-options1.67.0 libboost-regex1.67.0
  libboost-serialization1.67.0 liblxc1 libmotif-common libnma0 libpam-cgfs
  libprotobuf-lite17 libsdl2-image-2.0-0 libu2f-udev libxm4 lxc lxc-templates
  lxcfs network-manager-gnome qemu-utils squashfs-tools uidmap
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 127 not upgraded.
```

Comment: `zlib1g-dev` is the headers-package for compiling a C or C++ program to link to the zlib library.  AFAIK it does not have any effect on the behavior of your python interpreter, which may have been built without the zlib python module enabled.

Comment: Installing headers after you already have compiled Python without zlib support will bring no benefit. The headers have to be available to the C compiler. If you have built Python yourself, remove it and rebuild/reinstall. If you have installed built Python from somewhere else, ask package maintainer why Python was built without zlib support.

Answer (score -2):

Can you try to do this:
***sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev***